# Вызов статической переменной из другой функции

Tags: c, функции, переменные

Необходимо обратиться к статической переменной из другой функции. Пример в коде:

```
 void First(void)
 {
    static int a = 5;
 }

 void Second(void)
 {
    //Тут необходимо узнать значение переменной 'a' из функции 'Firts'
 }
```

Comment: "Легальными методами" это невозможно. В принципе же, можно воспользоваться таблицей символов в загрузочном модуле (если она не удалена) и аналогично тому, как это делает отладчик, вычислить адрес этой переменной в исполняемом образе.

Comment: Это достаточно сложно для моей программы. Проще огласить переменную глобальной.

Comment: В программе около 35-40 переменных. Даже понятно назвав их, путаюсь. Вот и раскинул все переменные в их функции.

Comment: Я никоим образом не призываю так поступать. Это чистой воды хак, так сказать искусство ради искусства. В вашем же случае, очевидно, что надо просто грамотно спроектировать программу, например, разбить ее на модули (единицы компиляции) с инкапсуляцией статических данных и функциями, обеспечивающими доступ к ним.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напрямую - никак. Область видимости статической переменной внутри функции ограничена самой этой функцией. Можно извернуться как-то так:

```
int *First( void ) 
{
    static int a = 0;
    return &a;
}
void Second( void ) {
    my *First_A_Pointer = First();
}
```

Но сама потребность в подобных извращениях говорит о том, что архитектура кода крайне непродумана, и её нужно менять. Без вариантов.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос возник после того, как множество объявлений переменных раскритиковали, и сказали, что неплохо было бы раскинуть все переменные в их функции. А теперь, когда понадобилось оперировать с переменными из других функций, пришлось обратно делать переменные глобальными.
После этого не понятно, что важнее: Удобный код, или нормальный доступ к переменным.

Comment: Важней - грамотная архитектура. А потребность "оперировать переменными из других функций" или "множество переменных"  - это не про неё.

Answer (score 4):

Пример не такой уж надуманный. 
Вот такой серьезный :) источник -

W. E. Brown, “Three -related proposals, v2,” Tech. Rep. N3742, ISO/IEC JTC 1, Information Technology, Subcommittee SC 22, Programming Language C++, August 2013.

Автор предлагает для начинающих упрощенный набор функций для работы со случайными числами. Поскольку движок надо иметь один (понятно, почему? :)), а глобальные переменные - очень плохо, его решение именно такое - статическая переменная, к которой имеют доступ *несколько* других функций (упрощенный код взят из книги "Discovering Miodern C++"):

```
#include <random>
std::default_random_engine& global_urng()
{
    static std::default_random_engine u{};
    return u;
}

void randomize()
{
    static std::random_device rd{};
    global_urng().seed(rd());
}

int pick(int from, int thru)
{
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> d{};
    using parm_t = decltype(d)::param_type;
    return d(global_urng(),parm_t{from,thru});
}

double pick(double from, double upto)
{
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> d{};
    using parm_t = decltype(d)::param_type;
    return d(global_urng(),parm_t{from,upto});
}
```

Так что, как видите, не всегда это "крайняя непродуманность"...